# When screen orientation changes, I want only one element to rotate

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-application, screen-orientation, expo-screen-orientation

I'm making an app with react native, expo, bottom-tab-bar navigation package, and expo-screen-orientation package.

The app is for reading some text that is inside some View elements in the middle of the screen, and is controlled with the bottom tab bar.

When I rotate the phone, and change the screen orientation (portrait-landscape), it kind of messes with the UI layout.
What I'd like to achieve, is to only have the View element that contains the readable text to rotate when the phone changes orientation, but the rest of the app (The bottom tab bar, background, buttons, etc.) to stay in the 'portrait' orientation.

What I've tried so far is this:
I've tried to lock the screen to portrait with

`ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.PORTRAIT);`
and then listening to orientation changes with eventListeners, Dimentions, useWindowDimentions, and expo-screen-orientation's  `ScreenOrientation.AddOrientationChangeListener(Listener)`,
and then maybe rotating the View element manually.

But if the screen is locked and not rotated, the change is not detected.

I've looked but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: UI rotation is triggered on the top-level/root/parent component, every child component inherits that new rotated position.  You can't easily make some component unsubscribe to that rotation.

Comment: Try to optimize your UI element layout to render effectively to each device orientation. There is utility library for this  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-screen